# Is it possible to connect to mysql server directly from an iOS app?

Tags: ios, mysql, iphone, backend

I was just wondering if we can connect to a mySql server directly from an iPhone app directly,i.e., without using any PHP or java scripts as intermediates. If Yes, then what will be the challenges? I understand that there might be a chance of hacking.

**EDIT:** What if I am in a VPN, is this still a threat?

Comment: Yes, security is the main concern. Never connect a DB directly via Internet & never expose DB port to the Internet. Make an API instead.

Comment: Thanks @Raptor, What if I am in a VPN, is this still a threat?

Comment: It's almost certainly *possible*; you can connect to a database from just about *any* programming language if you use a library (such as the [MySQL C library](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api.html). However, this question seems to be rather too broad for Stack Overflow, and is essentially a library recommendation in disguise.

Comment: it's better to be with VPN, but not all VPN tunnels are secured. Do not trust public VPN.